# Integration of Subversion version control with TFS bug tracking

Tags: version-control, integration, bug-tracking, tfsintegrationplatform

We are currently using Subversion for our version control software, and we have a license for TFS because we have MSDN.

I'm wondering if there is any tool that integrates TFS bug tracking with Subversion source control.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No.
Using TFS only makes sense when using all of its parts, it's quite hostile against integrating other components. 
If you need bugtracking and want to stick to SVN, you better use a free alternative like e.g. Bugzilla.

Thomas

Comment: Thanks.  I was afraid of this.

Comment: "No. Using TFS only makes sense when using all of its parts, it's quite hostile against integrating other components" - Very much disagree with this. I believe it makes more sense when using together, but that is true of all integrated solutions. However you can use bug tracking in TFS with SVN, there is no issues (especially hostile ones) that could stop you.

Comment: Very much disagree? Have you ever tried to integrate something like a pre-existing  MbUnit test battery in a TFS build. Or any other 3rd party solution except the one you mentioned? It's a shame! I strongly recommend to NOT use TFS to all my customers, because it's nearly impossible to create an open, adaptable environment with TFS - and the administration/infrastructure costs are much higher than with other solutions.

Comment: This is simply not true. There lot of tools which work with TFS AND Subversion.

Answer (score 0):

Integrate is an odd choice here, what do you wish to integrate? A work item can have any reference you like in it as it is just text.

TFS also supports customisation of work item fields so you could add fields for your SVN needs.

If you mean integrate the version control from SVN into TFS, then the TFS Integration Platform can help you with that.